# How, and where to install a database driver into an IDE?

Tags: delphi, installation, driver, firebird, delphi-xe

I want to install a Firebird database driver, and to have it available within the Delphi XE IDE. I want the database driver to be usable on the same basis as other, supplied database drivers (eg Interbase, SQL - from within the Data Explorer in the IDE). I have obtained an appropriate driver.

The driver consists of a Delphi project, which compiles to a DLL; and modifications to two .ini configuration files (dbxconnections.ini and dbxdrivers.ini). I assume that the DLL is the actual driver, and I have compiled the project without problem.

I have got this far, and this is where I realised that I do not know what is involved in installing a new database driver; what is involved in installing a new database driver into an IDE; nor where the elements of the installation need to reside.

So my question is:
What steps are needed to install a dbExpress database driver into the Borland XE Delphi Professional IDE?

Some of the specific points I don't know about include -

1. Does the driver need to be registered with all of Firebase, Delphi and Windows?
2. Do I need to employ a specific registration procedure to accomplish registration?
3. Are there any elements I am missing to accomplish my aim?
4. Where should the installed components be located?

All four vendors, Embarcadero, Borland, [UniOpen](http://www.koders.com/delphi/fidAEA249DB8D34B95D7229EDCCA286FF4FB70C73FB.aspx?s=%22Cardinal%22#L66), and Firebird provide documentation (most of which is very comprehensive) but I have been unable to extract from them what I need to do and where to do it.

I have searched multiple questions on SO, but all of seem to start from the basis that the OP knows what is involved in driver installation.

All the products (except the driver project) generate multiple files in multiple locations, and it is not clear what components belong where. For example, I have multiple versions of the two configuration files residing in:

1. C:\Users\User\AppData....
2. C:\Users\Public\Public Documents...
3. C:\Program Files\Vendor....
4. ....

In addition these products install files into:

1. the registry (multiple keys);
2. C:\Program Files....;
3. C:\Program Files (x86)....;
4. C:\Windows\System....;
5. C:\Windows\System 32.....
6. and probably more.

Environment:

- Machine: Lenovo Thinkpad W510
- OS: Windows 7 Ultimate
- Delphi: Embarcadero® RAD Studio XE Version 15.0.3953.35171
- Database: W1-V2.5.0.26074 Firebird 2.5
- Database Driver: UniOpen Native DBX Driver

Also Installed:

- Embarcado Borland® Developer Studio 2006 Enterprise Version 10.0.2288.42451 Update 2 (XP Version)
- Borland Delphi Version 7 (XP Version)

**In summary:**

*What steps and locations are needed to install a dbExpress database driver into the Borland XE Delphi Professional IDE?*

Comment: You appear to be confused over your versions. 2010 or XE? It sounds to me like you should contact the driver vendor. Having said that, according to Google, UniOpen don't exist.

Comment: Version confusion due to selection of wrong tag. Reference to a source of the UniOpen driver added.

Comment: @Chris it says 2010 right there at the bottom of the Q.

Comment: Why don't you use the built in Firebird driver in XE or if you are on the Pro version of XE use the one from devart? Sounds like you are trying to do it on the cheap.

Comment: Also, although the UniOpen driver is the one I have, I am not fixated on a specific driver, and would be quite willing to use another driver. This still leaves my original question - How do you install such a driver into an IDE?

Comment: I can't help you there but I thought XE came with Firebird dbx drivers.

Comment: @David: It depends on the SKU. Professional only comes with Interbase and MySQL (and BlackFish, of course). Enterprise and Architect add additional database drivers like Oracle, SQL Server, etc.

Comment: @David - corrected. I am using the Pro version of XE. As open solution is preferred as cost is a consideration - $100 dollars for a (comparatively) minor component is not completely trivial for someone retired. However, the Devart driver does look to provide the support infrastructure necessary to enable me to install the driver.

Comment: @chris come to think of it I suspect I'm using an old Firebird via the Delphi 6 Interbase drivers! I wonder if that approach would work with a more modern Delphi. I'm not suggesting that as a solution for you though, more thinking aloud for myself.

Comment: @David: It works, but some of the newer features of Firebird aren't supported (where it diverged from Interbase).

Comment: @ken Sometimes I am so dumb! I've been doing this for years and only now realised what I am actually doing! It's actually perfectly fine because I don't need any database features. Must make mental note not to upgrade Firebird. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed a file. :)

DataExplorer, from the best I can tell, uses dbxdrivers.ini. My installation of XE has a single copy of that particular file, located (Win7 64) in C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\8.0. The connection types listed in DataExplorer come from the list of installed drivers at the beginning of that file, and each driver has one or more configuration sections which follow that list.

The driver files listed in the configuration section have to exist in a location findable (like any other Windows DLL) by [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175%28VS.85%29.aspx). The documentation in the link explains the way the API function searches for DLLs; basically though, the IDE has to find it somewhere on the PATH.

The vendor or author of your particular driver should be able to provide the info that needs to go in the dbxdrivers.ini file. (I'm not familiar with UniOpen personally, and don't have FireBird on this particular machine.) The IDE only reads that file during startup, so you'll need to (re)start the IDE after making the additions.

[This](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=50632&tstart=0) post at the Embarcadero Delphi Database->DBExpress forum may help with defining aliases for your Firebird databases, and describes connecting via the TSQLConnection component. (Look for a post by Ralph Horbury-Smith.) If you don't have a Developer's Network ID, you'll need to register with the Embarcadero site; the link I provided uses HTTPS for some reason. You can also get to their forums via NNTP; I'm not using a newsreader, so I'm not sure what the address would be. There's a link to connection info on [this](http://dn.embarcadero.com/help/forums) page at Embarcadero.

There's also some [information](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Developing_Database_Applications) available on the Delphi XE documentation Wiki pages that might help as well.

EDIT: Found one more [link](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=50363&tstart=0) at the DBExpress forums that might interest you. It has a link for another FB DBExpress [driver](http://sites.google.com/site/dbxfirebird/) and specific information for the dbxdrivers.ini file for that driver. It's the post by Phillip Flores (about the 3rd one down on the page).

Answer (score 2):

I am accepting @Ken's answer. His response provided links to various resources. I am summarising the answers to the specific points I had that I have obtained from the references.

1. There is no need to amend dbxconnections.ini - the IDE will do that for me.
2. I need to amend dbxdrivers.ini appropriately and place it in the IDE directories.
3. The actual driver needs to be somewhere on the path - typically System32.
4. There is no need to register the driver with Windows.
5. Apart from the items listed above, there is no special procedure needed to register such drivers.
6. The list here appears complete.

**EDIT:**

My conclusions in this summary were premature and I have asked a [further question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480552/how-and-where-to-install-a-database-driver-into-an-ide-part-ii) to try and obtain further information. The strikeout in the list above marks the incorrect elements.